# I have a polybag of LEGO pieces and need the set they go with

Tags: set-identification

I have a polybag of LEGO pieces and need the set they go with.

There is one 6x6 large black square and ten light gray 1x2x2
with a small bag inside.

What set are they a part of?

[image: Picture of bag of LEGO pieces]

Answer (score 6):

This is [41611: Marty McFly & Doc Brown](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=41611-1), based on *Black Plate 6 x 6*, two of *Yellow Brick, Round 2 x 2 with Axle Hole*, at least 8 *Red Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Headlight* and the *Black Brick, Modified 1 x 2 x 2/3 with Studs on Sides*.

For future reference, you too can use Bricklink to identify the sets by entering the known parts into [this form](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogIn.asp?viewMulti=Y), to get an answer like [this](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=3958&itemSeq1=1&colorID1=11&itemNo2=3941&itemSeq2=2&colorID2=3&itemNo3=4070&itemSeq3=8&colorID3=5&in=S).

Comment: ok, from now on, we should mark every question for set identification as a duplicate and refer to this answer. Could you expand your answer how you get to that bricklink form rather than having to follow your URL ?

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve I'll try to write a dedicated question with a self-answer to refer to in the future on set identification.